# Unable to pass data dynamically in json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

```
var updFileId = "12345";

$scope.compGridJson = {
  "peers": ["localhost:7051", "localhost:8051"],
  "fcn": "move",
  "args": ["compGridDetails", "{" +
    "\"FromParty\":\"Valuelabs\",\"CreatedState\":\"24/08/2017\",\"FileUId\":\"+updFileId+\",\"Status\":\"ValueLabs Change Request\"}"
  ]
}
$http({
  method: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:4000/channels/mychannel/chaincodes/changedneww727",
  data: $scope.compGridJson,
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer token',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

});
```

Above is my code. In Json data for "FileUId" I'm passing data dynamically. But it is not taking data dynamically. I changed so many ways for that value but it is not taking dynamically.  I want to pass that "12345" value  dynamically.Can some one help me.

Comment: What is there instead of `12345`?

Comment: You are not ending the string around `+updFileId+`. It should look like `...\"FileUId\": \"" + a + "\"...`

Comment: @Björn It's working Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You string concatenation is not well formed. You should try:

```
$scope.compGridJson = {
  "peers": ["localhost:7051", "localhost:8051"],
  "fcn": "move",
  "args": ["compGridDetails", "{" +
    "\"FromParty\":\"Valuelabs\",\"CreatedState\":\"24/08/2017\",\"FileUId\":\""+updFileId+"\",\"Status\":\"ValueLabs Change Request\"}"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [json.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
$scope.compGridJson = {
        "peers": ["localhost:7051", "localhost:8051"],
        "fcn": "move",
        "args": ["compGridDetails",  JSON.stringify({
                                        FromParty : "Valuelabs",
                                        CreatedState: "24/08/2017",
                                        FileUId : updFileId,
                                        Status : "ValueLabs Change Request"
        })]
      }
```